# How do I specify another procmail script other than .procmailrc?

Tags: procmail, fetchmail

I am trying to set up two different environments (`development` and `test`) on a single machine where I am using fetchmail/procmail.  How would I specify a procmail script other than `.procmailrc`?

Answer (score 1):

You can optionally specify an alternate `rcfile` on the command line (or even multiple files).

```
$ procmail -h 2>&1 | head -n 4
Usage: procmail [-vptoY] [-f fromwhom] [parameter=value | rcfile] ...
   Or: procmail [-toY] [-f fromwhom] [-a argument] ... -d recipient ...
   Or: procmail [-ptY] [-f fromwhom] -m [parameter=value] ... rcfile [arg] ...
   Or: procmail [-toY] [-a argument] ... -z
```

See the ARGUMENTS section of the [manual page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/procmail/) for precise details.

With the `-m` option, the `rcfile` argument is mandatory.  It might be a good idea to use in your scenario, as it disables some defaults which make more sense when running as your default LDA.